# Implementation of new OCC feature into Spartacus framework

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I have a new feature called wishlist. This feature has separate OCC. how (and where) would you recommend I include the new OCC calls using your framework?

Answer (score 1):

We are currently developing this feature, so we would recommend to wait for it, if you can.
If you can't, you need APIs on the back-end, and you can use our connector / adapter patter to talk to a different system or custom APIs: https://sap.github.io/cloud-commerce-spartacus-storefront-docs/connecting-to-other-systems/#page-title